# getID from database of the Item clicked of a listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an app containing two activites. In each activity I have a listView with some content in there.

In first activity i have a listView of "Cours" inside. In the 2nd one I have another listView of "Notes".

I can add "Cours" and "Notes" by using SQLite. When I click on a "Cours", it opens the Notes Activity and it only shows the notes created for that ID ( I use FK).

Let's say I create a "Cours" called Maths. I click on it and I create a note "Test".
After If I click on Maths I can see in the other activity the note Test.

But, let's say I create a "Cours" called French. If I click on it I will have the note Test, and if I click on Math it will say that I have no notes.

This happens because my ListView is ordered by ASC. And i'm getting the ID of the position of my ListView.

At the beginning Math had ID 1. But when I created French, Math had ID 2 and French had ID1. But in my Database SQlite, Math has ID 1 and French has ID 2.

So : **How can I get the ID of the database instead of the ID of the position on the listView when I click on an item of the first ListView?**

Here's my ClickListener of my first ListView:

```
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            long itemid= lv.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
            int id= (int)itemid;
            String a =lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Intent b = new Intent(AffichageCours.this,AffichageNotes.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("nom_cours",a);
            args.putInt("id",id);
            b.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(b);
        }

    });
}
```

And in the second activity, how I recuperate the values :

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
    int id = args.getInt("id");
    String nom_cours = args.getString("nom_cours");
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The `long` value in the `onItemClick` should be the id if you used a cursor and your column has an id column of `_id`

Comment: How do I solve it so ? I mean, how do I use Cursor ?